# Forgot Password Django - password_reset (custom user model)

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, passwords

looking for help. I am beginner Python/Django developer.

**I have the following view:**

```
class UserForgotPasswordView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    with open(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + "/frontend/static/frontend/languages/emails/EN/email_footer__main.json", "r") as temp_file_email_footer_main:
        email_footer_main_data = json.load(temp_file_email_footer_main)
    with open(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + "/frontend/static/frontend/languages/emails/EN/email_user_forgotPassword.json", "r") as temp_file_email_forgot_password:
        email_forgot_password_data = json.load(temp_file_email_forgot_password)
    extra_email_context = { 'email_footer_static_json_text': email_footer_main_data,
                            'email_static_json_text': email_forgot_password_data,
                            'static_json_text': static_textLanguage, 
                            'static_json_textGlobal': static_textGlobal}
    html_email_template_name = '../frontend/templates/frontend/templates.emails/template.email_user_forgotPassword.html'
    from_email = 'numeratio <support@numeratio.com>'
    title = 'numeratio password reset'
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
    template_name = '../frontend/templates/frontend/templates.user/template.page_forgotPassword.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('password_reset_done')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                context = { 'email_subject': self.email_forgot_password_data['emailSubject'],
                            'static_json_text': static_textLanguage, 
                            'static_json_textGlobal': static_textGlobal}
                return self.render_to_response(context)
        except:
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('page_home'))
```

What I am trying to get is that if the user is authenticated(logged) if he tries to go the the forgot-password link he is redirected home. The template render fine if the user is not logged/anonymous However, I am getting the following error for authenticated users trying to access the page

> The view users.views.UserForgotPasswordView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I need help with the redirect. Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: The `self.request.user.is_authenticated` will only run if there is an exception in the `try` block. If the user is thus authenticated, the `except` part will *never* run.

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem, thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to elaborate with an code example or how to clean my code so it works? Again, I am not an expert Python/Django developer and just starting my journey